# Phonegap/Cordova ANDROID_HOME is set but won't work

Tags: android, cordova

I`m trying to make an android build of a phonegap project created using phonegap create.

I have set the env variables for ANDROID_HOME and PATH, etc. but it still won't work.

Am I missing something?

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Guilherme-GM:ssgt guilhermegm$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2
MacBook-Pro-de-Guilherme-GM:ssgt guilhermegm$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/platform-tools:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/tools
MacBook-Pro-de-Guilherme-GM:ssgt guilhermegm$ sudo cordova build android
cp: no such file or directory: /Users/guilhermegm/Projects/ssgt/frontend/ssgt/icon.png

cp: no such file or directory: /Users/guilhermegm/Projects/ssgt/frontend/ssgt/www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png

cp: no such file or directory: /Users/guilhermegm/Projects/ssgt/frontend/ssgt/www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png

Running command: /Users/guilhermegm/Projects/ssgt/frontend/ssgt/platforms/android/cordova/build
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
Error: /Users/guilhermegm/Projects/ssgt/frontend/ssgt/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
MacBook-Pro-de-Guilherme-GM:ssgt guilhermegm$
```

Comment: can you show me how you do it?

Comment: In my .bash_profile I added those env. variables

Comment: what is your android sdk path?

Comment: I have two sdks path: "/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2" and "/Users/guilhermegm/Library/Android/sdk"

Answer (score 1):

I've same problem like you, by the way what OS do you used ?
before i update my OS X to new version it's works perfectly.

I got same issues when add android platform in my cordova project,
when i register environment variable in ~/.bash_profile like this

```
#Android
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/donny/Documents/android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/donny/Documents/android/sdk/tools

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/donny/Documents/android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME:/platform-tools
```

Then i save it, and execute my new bash_profile

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

then i check ANDROID_HOME is already registered or not

```
$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
$ /Users/donny/Documents/android/sdk
```

as you can see it's return correctly

but when i close my terminal and open my terminal again, or open terminal in new tab and run

```
$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
$
```

it's return blank
i think it's issues by my OS X but i don't know exactly about that

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try this one inside your `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/android-sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/android-sdk/tools
```

Comment: I dont have an android-sdk folder inside Applicatons

Comment: change with your android sdk path

Answer (score 0):

Try checking that ANDROID_HOME is going to the proper sub directory. Since your platform tools is in "23.0.2" (/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/platform-tools) have ANDROID_HOME set to: `/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2`